# No color in terminal on KDE

Tags: terminal, kde, xterm, kubuntu

I have no colors in my terminal on KDE Kubuntu 16.04.1.

[image: Here it doesn't work]

here is my `.bashrc` (I copied it from an Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 but I always used this one also on former KUbuntu 12.04.)

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.                                                                                                                     
shopt -s checkwinsize                                                                                                                                         

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will                                                                                          
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.                                                                                            
#shopt -s globstar                                                                                                                                            

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)                                                                                           
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"                                                                                                  

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)                                                                                  
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then                                                                                             
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)                                                                                                                   
fi                                                                                                                                                            

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)                                                                                              
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\]\u\[\] @ \[\]\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\]$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s&zwj;/;s/[;&|]\s*alert$                                  //'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194039/no-terminal-colors-in-ubuntu-server-12-04) and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=66816) but I have no color in terminal nor via ssh though

```
> echo $TERM
xterm-color
```

Anyway the colored output of `apt update` or `ls -a` e.g. works

[image: la works to so color in general works]

only not the prompt which I would expect to look like on the other server where I copied the .bashrc from and where it is working:

[image: Here it works]

Is there something I'm missing? How can I get the colored prompt working? (Especially asking because I want my green and the root's red but none of both work)

Comment: What if you remove the conditional and just set the colored PS1? If you get a colored PS1 in that way, it means somehow the conditional doesn't work for you.

Comment: @AlvaroGMJ Thanks for your help. As John Smith already pointed out I copied the script the wrong way into the server so that PS1 never was set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I do not see any color-related syntax in your script

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\]\u\[\] @ \[\]\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\]$ '
```

When I call your code from my bash prompt

```
PS1='\[\]\u\[\] @ \[\]\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\]$ '
```

I see just white letters. You do not even have `export PS1`, which means that this variable never affects anything outside the script. My guess is that on your old machine some other script was responsible for colors.

In order to get the colors, which you have posted, try to call the following from your terminal

```
PS1='\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[0m\] @ \[\033[0;32m\]\h\[\033[0m\]:\[\033[31m\]\W\[\033[0m\]\$ '
```

if it works, put

```
export PS1='\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[0m\] @ \[\033[0;32m\]\h\[\033[0m\]:\[\033[31m\]\W\[\033[0m\]\$ '
```

into your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: A big huge facepalm here on my side :D ... What I did: I used `cat .bashrc` on the one server and copy pasted the output to the other server... What happened: Ofcourse (stupid me) when I did `cat .bashrc` the code e.g. `}\[^[[01;32m\]\u\[^[[00m\]` got printed out as a fad green string like `\]\u\[` :D :D didn't notice that line when I just copied the whole output of cat.

Comment: no problem, similar things happened to me too on numerous occasions) thanks for marking my answer. but in future better use `scp` or `rsync` for moving files between servers.

Comment: yeah I usually use those or sometimes even nano .. but this time I wanted to be fast ... :P turned out to be slower than the usual :D